# Django models relations: connect field to instances of itself

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I am creating a network devices tracker where I want interfaces to be connected to one another only on some criteria. I am however stack at trying to connect interfaces together. I think my models logic is not right as in InterfaceConnection I am connecting an interface to a Device, not another interface.

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .constants import ROLES, FORM_FACTORS


class Device(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=False, null=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLES, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Device #{self.id} - hostname {self.hostname}"


class Interface(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(to=Device, to_field="hostname", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interface")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    form_factor = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=FORM_FACTORS, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Interface #{self.id} - {self.name}"


class InterfaceConnection(models.Model):
    interface = models.ForeignKey(to=Interface, blank=True, null=True, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interface_connection")
    device = models.ForeignKey(to=Device, blank=False, null=False, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interface_connection")
    
    def clean(self) -> None:
        if self.interface and self.interface.form_factor == 'virtual':
            raise ValidationError({
                "interface":
                "virtual interface cannot be connected to any other interface"
            })
        return super().clean()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("interface", "device")
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Connection #{self.id} - interface {self.interface.name} - device {self.device.hostname}"
```

How do I express this type of relationship? I appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 0):

You can self-reference a model by referencing the model name or using the keyword `'self'`.

```
class Interface(models.Model):
    connected_interface = models.ForeignKey('Interface', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interface_connection")
```

or

```
class Interface(models.Model):
    connected_interface = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interface_connection")
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! does this mean I don't need InterfaceConnection anymore?

Comment: @MurphyAdam, this depends many things such as whether you want to add additional data to the connection (right now you wouldn't loose any information if you get rid of the InterfaceConnection model) and general design preferences. If you want to use a separate InterfaceConnection model, I would simply define two fields, interface_1 and interface_2. These two would then form a connection.